# rendered image looks distorted or blurry

Tags: rendering, animation, image

[image]

[image]

When I rendered the animation as images, the images produced looked somehow distorted or blurry. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: This is Noise try increasing Samples. Under Render Tab>Sampling & increase Render Samples.

Comment: Enable denosing